# Why is the following code not returning True(comparing the symmetry of a binary Tree)

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I am comparing the symmetry in a binary tree which means I am checking if the left sub tree is equal to the right sub tree or not

The code is failing for the following input using BFS approach:

Input Test Case: `[1,2,2,3,4,4,3] #list of nodes of the Tree`

Output: `False`

Expected Output:`True`

The Tree is defined as the following Class:

```py
 class TreeNode:
     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
         self.val = val
         self.left = left
         self.right = right
```

My Code:

```py
     def isSymmetric( root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
             q=[(root.left,root.right)]     #The Queue
             while q:
                 p=q.pop(0)
                 if p[0]==p[1]:
                     if p[0]:                #checking if we have reached None (leaf)
                         q.append((p[0].left,p[1].right))
                         q.append((p[0].right,p[1].left))
                 else:
                     return False
           
             return True
```

This is the Tree representation for the Test case:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCPbQ.png)

I am not trying to lookup for solution I want to know why the above code is not working to clear my concepts.

Comment: Why do you think it should return `True`? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Comment: `p[0]==p[1]` is testing two `TreeNode` objects for equality, but you haven’t defined any such concept.  You either need to define a `__eq__()` method, or explicitly compare `val` attributes.